# I am trying to check for undefined but it's not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$scope.$watch("pid", _.debounce(function (pid) {

    var a = pid;

    $scope.$apply(function (pid) {
        if (typeof pid == "undefined" || pid == null || pid === "") {
            $scope.pidLower = null;
            $scope.pidUpper = null;
        }
        else if (pid.indexOf("-") > 0) {
            pid = pid.split("-");
            $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0]);
            $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1]);
        }
        else {
            $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid);
            $scope.pidUpper = null;
        }
    });
}, 1000));
```

The very first time the code runs (when the pid field is empty) I check pid with the google development tools and it shows as "undefined". However when the code runs it does not go into the first if condition. Rather it goes to the second and gives an error saying:

TypeError: Object # has no method 'indexOf'

Can anyone tell me why it ignores the first if statement ?

Here is what I get when I use the console to check pid on the first line with an if:

```
console.log(typeof pid)
object
undefined
```

Comment: If it is undefined, then it should go into the first condition. Try producing a *complete* reduced test case so we can see the problem.

Comment: From seeing the error message and that it goes to the second condition, I would think that it is actually defined, but does not have a method `indexOf` (meaning that it is not a string or an array). Are you sure you are inside the correct scope when checking for the variable in devtools? Can you `console.log(typeof pid)`?

Comment: @SoonDead - I did the console log and updated the question.

Comment: How do you declare $scope.pid in your controller? Can not set it to null instead of undefined at the start?

Comment: Why do you have a `pid` parameter in the function passed for `$scope.$apply`? It hides the outer `pid` parameter. You should try it with the inner `pid` removed. Like `$scope.$apply(function () { ... code ... });`

Comment: Also, you don't need to use $apply at all in this case. Since this is carried out in a $watch-statement, the scope will be dirtychecked automatically after the function has completed anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is what I get when I use the console to check pid on the first line with an if:
>
> ```
> console.log(typeof pid)
> object
> undefined
> ```

This says that the type of pid is **an object**. It *then* says that the return value of `console.log()` is `undefined`.

It isn't going into the first `if` because the variable is not, as you thought, undefined.

It then fails because, whatever kind of object `pid` is, it isn't one with an `indexOf` method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (!pid) {
                $scope.pidLower = null;
                $scope.pidUpper = null;
            }
            else if (pid.indexOf("-") > 0) {
                pid = pid.split("-");
                $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0]);
                $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1]);
            }
            else {
                $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid);
                $scope.pidUpper = null;
            }
```